# Merging four decoded frames into one big frame and then display it using ijkplayer

Tags: merge, decode, ijkplayer

Can anyone please help me providing advice on how to merge four decoded frames from four different videos and then send it to display.

I observed in video_refresh() function decoded frames are dequeued from framebuffer

**vp = frame_queue_peek(&is->pictq);**

then *video_display2()* is called inside, *video_image_display2()* displayed on the screen using *SDL_VoutDisplayYUVoverlay* API.

**I want to merge four frames (vp_1, vp_2, vp_3, vp_4) obtained from four videos into final frame vp and then display on the screen.**

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this. What modifications I have to make in ff_ffplay.c code. Any sort of help will highly be appreciated.